# Open and save do not work in very simple Swift 4 document-based application

Tags: swift, xcode, macos, cocoa, swift4

I did some Swift programming a while ago in Swift 2 and am now trying to use Swift 4. Maybe I'm missing something really obvious, but I cannot for the life of me get an extremely simple document-based text-editor application to open or save files properly. I make the document-based application and add this code to the ViewController class:

```
@IBOutlet var theTextView: NSTextView!
```

Then I go to the storyboard, add a Text View to it, and connect that Text View to theTextView as an outlet. I added data and read functions to Document as follows:

```
override func data(ofType typeName: String) throws -> Data {

    if let vc = self.windowControllers[0].contentViewController as? ViewController {
        return vc.theTextView.string.data(using: String.Encoding.utf8) ?? Data()
    }
    else {
        return Data()
    }

}

override func read(from data: Data, ofType typeName: String) throws {

    if let s = String(data: data, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8) {
        string = s
    }

    throw NSError(domain: NSOSStatusErrorDomain, code: unimpErr, userInfo: nil)
}
```

The program compiles and runs. But whenever I try to save, no save dialogue comes up and the app becomes unable to quit (I have to stop it from within Xcode). Whenever I try to open a file in the format I set for the app (even if it's just .txt), I get the error "The document [filename] could not be opened." I get that exact same behaviour even when all I do is add the TextView to the view controller, with no outlets or code added. So clearly Cocoa is not recognizing my code and/or outlets as relevant, but I cannot for the life of me figure out why. What am I missing?

Comment: `data(ofType:)` just return the contents of the text view as `Data`, nothing else, and in the `read` method you are throwing the error in any case. By the way: A `String` created from UTF8 encoded `Data` and `Data` created from an UTF8 encoded `String` can never fail. Force unwrap the objects, the `if - let` expressions are pointless.

Comment: Getting rid of the "throws" seemed to fix the read method, thanks. I got rid of the optionals so the data function just contains

`let vc = self.windowControllers[0].contentViewController as! ViewController`

`return vc.theTextView.string.data(using: String.Encoding.utf8)!`

and there's no chance of it returning just `Data` in the way there was before, but the same thing happens.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Getting rid of the "throw" above fixed the read method, as vadian suggested.

The data method required two fixes. First, apparently nobody tells you that [you now need to set permissions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47954418/using-cocoa-nssavepanel-in-swift-causes-assertion-failure) to be able to write a file. I had to do that, following the instructions at the link.

Second, I think I needed to drop the "self" when getting the view controller? I'm not entirely sure why this worked, but I played around with the code more and changed it to

```
var viewController: ViewController? {
    return windowControllers[0].contentViewController as? ViewController
}

override func data(ofType typeName: String) throws -> Data {
    let textView = viewController?.theTextView
    if let contents = textView?.string.data(using: String.Encoding.utf8)
    {
        return contents
    }
    throw NSError(domain: NSOSStatusErrorDomain, code: unimpErr, userInfo: nil)
}
```

And *that* successfully saves.